# jspdf prints blank with addHTML

Tags: jspdf

I'm getting blank page when using jsPDF features. My code as below

```
<div id="content">  
        <a href="#" onclick="return printDiv();">
            <img src="../res/css/print.png" alt="Cetak" id="imgPrint" />
        </a>
        <div id="divChart">
            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel">
                <telerik:RadOrgChart RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadOrgChart1" runat="server" EnableCollapsing="true"
                    EnableGroupCollapsing="true" Skin="Default" />
            </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
        </div>
</div>
```

And for the js this is the code which gets the html and prints it out to pdf

```
function printDiv() {
            console.log("masuk printdiv");
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            var options = {
                pageSplit: true
            };

            pdf.addHTML($('#divChart')[0], function () {
                pdf.save("test.pdf");
            });


}
```